# change coordinates of L.Marker in L.layerGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I cannot find way how to change coordinates of layer(L.Marker) placed in layerGroup.
I created global variable `var markerGroup = new L.layerGroup();`

Then I have a function where  I'm creating layers like:

```
var newMarker = L.marker([decimal_lat, decimal_lon]);
markerGroup.addLayer( newMarker );
```

And I have a modal dialog window where I'm changing coordinates of Markers ( depends on id what Marker from my layer I change ):

```
(markerGroup.getLayer(id)).setLatLngs( L.latLng(parseFloat(lat_p), parseFloat(lon_p)) );
```

But this solution makes error like:

> Cannot read property 'setLatLngs' of undefined

Is there any way how to change coordinates of L.Marker on specific position in L.layerGroup?

Answer (score 3):

Marker layers don't have `setlatLngs` method, they do have [`setLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setlatlng). Most probably you've made a typo error.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgg44tkq/9/) where I've correctly reproduced your issue. At first I've added a marker with arbitrary coordinates, then I've moved it to the centre of the map, exactly where map view is set.

```
var markerGroup = new L.layerGroup();
var newMarker =  L.marker([1000, 1000]);
markerGroup.addLayer( newMarker );
markerGroup.addTo(map);   
markerGroup.getLayer(24).setLatLng(new L.LatLng(0,0));
```

Comment: really, you are right, but can I ask you, why do you use in getLayer() method number 24? I thought it should be 0, because of length of MarkerGroup..

Comment: `getLayer()` receives  the id of the layer as the argument, not it's index in `LayerGroup`. You can see it here: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayer. Iterate through the marker group to see the id of each layer: `markerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    console.log(layer._leaflet_id);
 });`

Comment: That means that ids for layers are auto generated, right?

Comment: Yes, if you wish to get a layer by the index, you can iterate through all the layers (with `eachLayer` method) till the iteration order equals to the index you need.